# Парсинг xml-файла с вложенными классами

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, импорт, export

пытаюсь импортировать xml-файл в MS SQL Server и вроде бы как получилось, но работает не так как нужно. Вот сам xml-файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOCTORS>
    <DOCTOR>
        <surname>Никитина</surname>
        <name>Нина</name>
        <patronymic>Петровна</patronymic>
        <profession>Терапевт</profession>
        <category>1</category>
        <PATIENT>
            <surname>Понамарев</surname>
            <name>Олег</name>
            <patronymic>Игнатьевич</patronymic>
            <date_birth>12.02.1997</date_birth>
            <category>Инвалид</category>
            <NOTES>
                <date_note>01.03.2020</date_note>
                <diagnos>ОРВИ</diagnos>
                <price>560</price>
            </NOTES>
        </PATIENT>
        <PATIENT>
            <surname>Николаев</surname>
            <name>Георгий</name>
            <patronymic>Николаевич</patronymic>
            <date_birth>17.11.1985</date_birth>
        </PATIENT>
    </DOCTOR>
    <DOCTOR>
        <surname>Романовна</surname>
        <name>Светлана</name>
        <patronymic>Николаевна</patronymic>
        <profession>Дерматолог</profession>
        <category>6</category>
    </DOCTOR>
</DOCTORS>
```

Код:

```
// импортирую данные доктора

            var items_doctor = doc.Descendants("DOCTOR")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Surname = (string)x.Element("surname"),
                    Name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                    Patronymic = (string)x.Element("patronymic"),
                    Profession = (string)x.Element("profession"),
                    Category = (string)x.Element("category")
                });

            foreach (var el in items_doctor)
            {
                using (var context = new MyDbContext())
                {
                    var doctor = new Doctor
                    {
                        Family_name = el.Surname,
                        Name = el.Name,
                        Patronymic = el.Patronymic,
                        Profession = el.Profession,
                        Category = el.Category
                    };


                    context.Doctors.Add(doctor);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

                MessageBox.Show("Операция завершена успешно!");
```

Проблема в том, что добавляются сперва все доктора без информации о его пациентах, а нужно чтоб информация об одном докторе и о его пациентах загружалась, затем переходим к следующему доктору и т.д.

Не могли бы вы подсказать как можно считать информацию с файла вот таким образом:

> DOCTOR считали всю информацию => PATIENT  считали всю информацию =>
>   NOTES считали всю информацию => PATIENT  считали всю информацию

Переходим к следующему:

> DOCTOR считали всю информацию => ...

Comment: ну как то хитро вы все это достаете ! почему не сделать десериализацию в класс , a  после этого работать с классом ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### вот решение

создаете классы

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "NOTES")]
    public class NOTES
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "date_note")]
        public string Date_note { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "diagnos")]
        public string Diagnos { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PATIENT")]
    public class PATIENT
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "patronymic")]
        public string Patronymic { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "date_birth")]
        public string Date_birth { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NOTES")]
        public NOTES NOTES { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DOCTOR")]
    public class DOCTOR
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "patronymic")]
        public string Patronymic { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "profession")]
        public string Profession { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PATIENT")]
        public List<PATIENT> PATIENT { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DOCTORS")]
    public class DOCTORS
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DOCTOR")]
        public List<DOCTOR> DOCTOR { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Класс Десериализации

```
//библиотеки
```

using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Xml.Serialization;

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс для XML сериализации/десериализации 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Любой тип класса</typeparam>
class XmlSerialization<T>
{
    private Object _obj = typeof(T);
    /// <summary>
    /// Метод десриализует файл в формате XML
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">Путь к файлу</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Переменная класса</param>
    /// <returns>возврашает object который надо приводить к типу класса (ClassType)</returns>
    public Object ReadData(string filePath, Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                obj = (T)xser.Deserialize(fs);
                fs.Close();
            }
            return obj;
        }   
            throw new Exception("file does not exist");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Метод сериализует класс в формат XML и пишет его в файл
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">путь к файлу для записи</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Переменная класса</param>
    public void WriteData(string filePath, Object obj)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath)) File.Delete(filePath);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xser.Serialize(fs, obj);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

### Сам процесс десириализации

> Может я не понимаю но NODES у пациента должны быть в списке, а то счас получается что на одного пациента только одна запись , но это уже вам решать

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            XmlSerialization<DOCTORS> xmlSerialization = new XmlSerialization<DOCTORS>();

            DOCTORS dc = new DOCTORS();

            string filePath = @"S:\t.xml"; // путь к файлу

            dc = (DOCTORS)xmlSerialization.ReadData(filePath, dc); //дерсериализация 


            for (int i = 0; i < dc.DOCTOR.Count; i++)//обходим докторов 
            {
                //добавляете доктора в базу 
                string doctorName = dc.DOCTOR[i].Name;
                string doctorSurname = dc.DOCTOR[i].Surname;
                string doctorCategory = dc.DOCTOR[i].Category;
                string doctorProfession = dc.DOCTOR[i].Profession;
                string doctorPatronymic= dc.DOCTOR[i].Patronymic;


                for (int j = 0; j < dc.DOCTOR[i].PATIENT.Count; j++)// обходим пациентов 
                {
                    // добавляйте пациента в базу к этому доктору 
                    //пациенты доктора 
                    string patienName = dc.DOCTOR[i].PATIENT[j].Name;
                    string patienSurname = dc.DOCTOR[i].PATIENT[j].Surname;
                    string patienCategory = dc.DOCTOR[i].PATIENT[j].Category;
                    string patienDateBirth = dc.DOCTOR[i].PATIENT[j].Date_birth;

                     //записи по пацианту (одна запись на пациента ? тоесть больше он не когда балеть не будет ? не понятно должен быть список )
                if(dc.DOCTOR[i].PATIENT[j].NOTES!=null)
                {
                    string patiendDateNote = dc.DOCTOR[i].PATIENT[j].NOTES.Date_note;
                    string patiendDiagnos = dc.DOCTOR[i].PATIENT[j].NOTES.Diagnos;
                    string patiendPrice = dc.DOCTOR[i].PATIENT[j].NOTES.Price;
                }

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Прошу прошения, а сможете ли Вы подсказать как сделать экспорт из БД в точно такой же xml-файл

Comment: точно также сначало заполняете класс  `DOCTORS dc = new DOCTORS();` данными потом используйте метод `public void WriteData(string filePath, Object obj)` чтобы сохранить данные в файл

Comment: А как получать информацию из базы данных, чтоб она имела такую же структуру что и сам импорт файл ? Ведь если я напишу просто запрос `var q = context.Doctors.Select()...`, то я получу информацию не структурированную.